# Show items with no data on rows | SSAS , MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

Working on a task that required to bring all a dimension’s data to the Pivot Table(Excel Sheet) even if they are not related to the fact.

first I was able to do it by using the option “PivotTable Options” -> “Display” -> “Show items with no data on rows” from Excel. The problem here is that using this option is going to affect the other dimensions and the requirement is to only this work for the Student dimension only and the user doesn’t like to keep changing the option back every time. then I found this solution using SCOPE, below, but just like above I could not find an away to just have the scope ignore the logic if any other dimension added so the data does not get duplicated.

```
SCOPE ([Program].[Program Hierarchy].MEMBERS, [Measures].[Number of Students]); 
THIS = IIF(ISEMPTY([Measures].[Number of Students]), 0, ([Measures].[Number of Students])); 
END SCOPE;
```

So is there something that I can add the SCOPE above to just work in the program dimension and get ignore/ skip and work as normal if any other dimension added to the pivot table?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets suppose that for Dimension1 ,attribute1, and the attribute "Value 1", you had nothing in Fact, so this is removed from the result, now you forced Excel to display it by selecting the option. When you add another dimension's attribute lets say Dimension2.Attribute1, since "Value 1" had nothing in Fact, therefore Cube will not understand which value of of Dimension2.Attribute1 is to be displayed in front of Dimension1.Attribute1, therefore it will display all its values. So if we have 3 values in Dimension2, attribute 1 then "Value 1" will be repeated three times. Now with Excel you cannot solve the issue, however it might just be possible to write an MDX query that works.

Edit: Query Added.

The below sample query is based on AdventureWorks, the first sample shows that the result has some nulls, if i un-comment the "non-empty" all null values will vanish, go ahead try it.

```
select [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on columns,
--non empty
[Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory]
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

Result without non empty
[image]

Now lets add another dimension to the query. Notice that the null value for the first row(Bib-shorts) is now repeated for all values of the second dimension, Since cube has no way to determine which value to display.

```
select [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on columns,
--non empty
([Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory],[Date].[Calendar Quarter of Year].[Calendar Quarter of Year])
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

Result
[image]

Now the above result shows the issue you are facing. What we now need to do is whenever there is a null value we dont need the individual members of the second dimension, rather a place holder to satisfy the tuple, will work.

In the query below I have two tuples 
1) for the not null data-points. Here we display the actual member of the second dimension. 
2) for the null data-points, here we use ".defaultmember" which basically means that the second dimension will behave as it was never selected. Have a close look at the second dimension it says "All Period"

```
select [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] on columns,
--non empty 
{filter(([Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory],[Date].[Calendar Quarter of Year].[Calendar Quarter of Year]),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]>0),
filter(([Product].[Subcategory].[Subcategory],[Date].[Calendar Quarter of Year].defaultmember),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]=null)
}
on rows 
from 
[Adventure Works]
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I actually start using the MDX query below, but I am trying to find a way to ignore the SCOPE logic if any other dimension is added and have the cube to work as usual.

SCOPE ([Program].[Program Hierarchy].MEMBERS, [Measures].[Number of Students]); THIS = IIF(ISEMPTY([Measures].[Number of Students]), 0, ([Measures].[Number of Students])); END SCOPE;

Comment: @Mohammad Hamad, welcome to MDX, your issue is not the scope statement. Even if there is no scope statement, when a value is missing in the fact and you display it, there is a natural cross join with all other dimensions's values.

Comment: Thanks, Moaz, do you have any example of this?


Cheers!

Comment: @Mohammad Hamad I dont have one at the moment,  however I can try to find one.

Comment: Please, I really appreciated. Also, let me know if there is no work around.

Comment: @Mohammad Hamad I guess you are using Excel as UI, if that is so then I dont think  it is possible, since Excel has MDX generator, which will not be able to generate MDX for it. You would need to write custom MDX to solve the issue(need to see if this can be done, will try but not sure).

Comment: @Mohammad Hamad does the above query help?

Comment: Hi Moaz, the query works, but when start expands to more dimension it becoming very complex. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Mohammad Hamad you are welcome.if the query works you should mark it as answer.